# Programmatic control over refreshing of external data in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

We have an internal system which produces excel reports that get their data direct from the Database via tables and pivot tables that use external connections.

However, these reports sometimes need to be sent to external clients whereupon, obviously the connections will fail and they'll get bug reports and an empty report.

In the workbook VBA, we've got the following function which is supposed to check if the connection is valid:

```
Public Function ConnectADO() As Boolean

    Dim retry As Boolean
    Dim provider As String
    Dim ConnectionString As String

    On Error Resume Next

    retry = False
    ConnectADO = False

    ConnectionString = "MyConnectionString"
    If mycon Is Nothing Then
        Set mycon = New ADODB.Connection
        mycon.CommandTimeout = 30
        mycon.ConnectionTimeout = 1 'so external clients aren't waiting ages
        mycon.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        mycon.Open ConnectionString
    End If

    If (mycon.State <> 1) Then
        ConnectADO = False
        Set mycon = Nothing
    Else
        ConnectADO = True
    End If

    If Err Then
        ConnectADO = False
        Set mycon = Nothing
    End If

End Function
```

The function is invoked when the spreadsheet is opened and none of the import code is run or refreshed if the connection fails. But this feels like a clumsy method of doing it - one slow network day, someone internal is going to get bitten by that `ConnectionTimeout = 1` for starters. And if someone forgets to save a filled copy of the sheet specifically for the client, they'll get an empty spreadsheet.

Is there a more nuanced way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having your code create a new workbook to save the data you want to export.  Send that new file to your clients. This accomplishes several things:

- You need not worry about sending blank workbooks to your client
- You won't be sending macros to your client, which will avoid their seeing security warnings
- You can increase the timeout in your code, because it will no longer have an effect on your clients

Comment: We actually started out down that route, but abandoned it because we found working with DocumentFormat.OpenXml to be an unending nightmare of burning horror. So reverted to templates with external connections. I'm loathe to go back down that path :(

Comment: I must be missing something then.  I don't understand why you would have any trouble working with a different file.  You can create new workbooks from existing workbooks so you can still make use of an existing "template" (this "template" can be a plain old .xls or .xlsx file, not necessarily an Excel .xlt or .xlst template file).   For example, `Set wb = Workbooks.Add("C:\Path\To\MyTemplate.xls")`. At that point, the only changes necessary to your code are to change references from `ActiveWorkbook` to `wb`.